# How can I restore the lost official Android SDK Update Sites?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Before, I set custom Update Sites for replacing default Android SDK Update Sites:

[image]

but them seems invalid, how can I restore the default sites of Google?

Answer (score 0):

click on enable panel check box then "Reset" button will appear top right hand site corner
click on reset.
try to modified the url of custum link
this will reset to default.[image]

Comment: In my case you see the `Enable` status is red exclamation mark, I can not select it. and in my panel there is no `Reset` button on the right top corner.

Comment: Did you try to edit the custum link (that mark red) ?

Comment: I can edit, but there will not show the checkbox and the reset button.

Comment: can u give the link so i can give a try